# Egg pasta vs. water+semolina pasta texture

Tags: eggs, pasta, texture

I recently started experimenting with making pasta from *semolina flour* and *water*. I noticed it has a slightly "slimy" texture after cooking, compared to that made with *eggs*.

Is it supposed to be like that? If not, should I knead it more? Or add more flour?

Comment: Was the dough slimy only after the initial mixing, or was it still slimy after kneading/resting/rolling out?

Comment: My inclination would be "too much water", but I can't say I've ever had it be "slimy".

Comment: @sneftel I was referring to the cooked pasta, sorry for the confusion!

Comment: @FuzzyChef that was my gut feeling too, although the dough was pretty hard when I was kneading it. I'll try to add some more flour next time and see when it starts breaking :-)

Comment: Oh, after cooking?  That's a different matter.  What's the grind on your semolina flour?  Semolina for pasta should be coarse-ground, like almost cornmeal-sized.

Comment: What grain is your semolina made from?

Comment: @FuzzyChef yes, it's exactly this coarse, and it's durum wheat. It actually says on the package that it's a pasta flour. Adding more flour to the dough improved the texture a bit, but my main question I guess is should there even be a discernible difference between an egg pasta and plain wheat pasta?

Comment: @rumtscho see above ^

Comment: There should be, but not the difference you're getting.  Egg pasta should be a bit stretchier and more flexible, and pure semolina pasta should be dry and brittle (when uncooked).  That's why folks don't tend to make semolina+water pasta at home that much.

Comment: @FuzzyChef ah, that's a clue! I was afraid to add even more flour exactly because it was getting brittle, especially around the edges when being run through a pasta machine. Looks like that's exactly what I need?

Comment: You could also try mixing in a little bread flour, just to give it more flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

usually in Italy, when we make "homemade" pasta without eggs, we used to leaving the pasta some hours to dry. If the pasta is drier, the "slimy" effect tends to fade.